# prevent overwriting file

Tags: php, ajax, json

Have a problem with files json

http://jsfiddle.net/XLkqH/

its my code and my code php is here:

```
<?php
   $json = $_POST['json'];

   /* sanity check */
     $file = fopen('../js/json/nameplaylist.json','w+');
     fwrite($file, $json);
     fclose($file);

?>
```

I need that when the name is saved, I can not overwrite the entire file sinuses, which I added to the end of the list and then display it in a select

**SOLVED:**

```
<?php
$in_array = json_decode($_POST['json'], true);
$file_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('../js/json/nameplaylist.json'), true);
$new_array = array_merge($file_array, $in_array);
file_put_contents('../js/json/nameplaylist.json', json_encode($new_array));
?>
```

Comment: So you want to merge the existing file with the new data, or just add the new data to the end of the existing file?  Why not just read the existing file contents, merge as arrays, then replace?

Comment: Try retieving the data form the file and then append the new $json to the old data, then rewrite it.

Comment: (FYI) Use `a+` to append. `w+` overwrites content.

Comment: @aerojun - it wouldn't be an append, I don't think, but a merge.  To append, the OP would just need to change the fopen mode to `a+` instead of `w+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$in_array = json_decode($_POST['json'], true);
$file_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('../json/nameplaylist.json'), true);
$new_array = array_merge($file_json, $in_json);
file_put_contents('../json/nameplaylist.json', json_encode($new_array));
```

You can't just add the new JSON to the end of the file, because then the file will contain lots of separate JSON arrays. You have to concatenate the arrays and then rewrite the whole file.

Comment: Would json_decode return an empty array if file_get_contents can't find the file (because it is first go-around with that file name)?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. You can simply initialize the file with `[]` before deploying the application. Or you could add error checking to my code to set `$file_array = array();` if it's empty.

Comment: i have a question, its im find, but when try save json return null file json how can fix?

Comment: solved var is wrong in $new_array = array_merge($file_json, $in_json);